# Image has background when i print but not on the screen

Tags: background, images

I have put a psd images in my illustrator document, when I made them in Photoshop I made the background transparent and the images look like they have no background on the screen but when I print it out you can see it has a slight shadow around the image which dulls the colour behind were I have put the image. 
Any advise appreciated.

Comment: If at all possible, you should use InDesign for composite jobs like these. It's made for combining different image types and still print flawlessly.

Comment: Are you 100% certain, without fail, that this "slight shadow" does *not* exist in the .psd files? Just because it doesn't show on screen, doesn't mean it's not there. A poorly calibrated monitor may not show a 1-3% color (or scum dot) where a print may. You can hover your cursor over the area in Photoshop and watch the **info Panel** to see if there is actually color there.

Answer (score 1):

If you used a layer mask, make sure your black color recipe is 100% in all CMYK (Cyan 100, Magenta 100, Yellow 100 and Black 100).

If you use the default black to do your masking, it's possible there will be a bit of transparency on your mask and show the background. It's often hard to see so maybe that's why your background looks perfectly transparent in Photoshop!

Answer (score 0):

Print the image directly from PhotoShop where there is no background.

You can also export the image to a `.png` without a background and then print the `.png`.

Comment: PNG is commonly **not** a correct format for printing.

Comment: 1) A well prepared mask is a well prepared mask, regardless of the format you save it. 2) You are implying that Brooke worked in RGB which could not be the case. 3) Besides he is saying he needs a background he has prepared in Ilustrator.

Answer (score 0):

A transparent background its not the same as "no background" at all in a digital file. In this case the background is only "covered" with the mask. To remove that information you need to make a new layer out of this mask, and delete the original layer. Of course always save your original files.

This will have the aditional benefit that the file size will be smaller, becouse there is no bacground data at all.

But if the final porpuse of the image is for printing there is no sense in making a file with transparencies at all, you can just make that zone white and flatten the image.

Comment: errmm.. masks actually *do* hide areas for printing. A properly masked area won't print.

Comment: Yeap. I agree. But sometimes an aplication can discard the mask and reveal the background. Probably I could have explained that. :o) Probably not this exact case...

Comment: One thing that i feel strange about the case. Only a "slight shadow" shows. Probably that is becouse you have a low resolution file. Probably you could post a  file online.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and although I couldn't find the root cause, I found that opening the .ai file in photoshop then printing from photoshop solved the issue. You can always save it as a .pdf from photoshop which will also print fine.